# Поехала вёрстка при отображении в "в лучших Х процентов на этой неделе"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, дизайн

Попал на первое место в недельном зачёте и увидал **поехавшую вёрстку**.

*См. скриншот:*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Экран: `1366х768`, браузер: `хром`.

@VladD и @PashaPash с этим, наверное, тоже постоянно сталкиваются?..